# Implementing simultaneous keystrokes for game

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

In my Java 2D game, two tanks are controlled as follows:

Tank 1

- Move forward: UP arrow
- Adjust angle of movement: LEFT and RIGHT arrows

Tank 2

- Move forward: W key
- Adjust angle of movement: A and D keys

It is possible to adjust the angle of a tank while it's moving forward (e.g., striking the left arrow or the right arrow while striking the up arrow). It's also possible to move both tanks forward simultaneously.

However, while one tank is moving forward **and** changing its angle (e.g., striking the up and the left/right key at the same time), the other tank is only able to move forward. That is to say, it cannot adjust its angle (e.g., striking W and A at the same time won't work, while the other tank is doing the same thing; the A key is ignored).

Why is that? Here's the relevant code:

In the `Board` class, that has most of the game logic:

```
while( game_is_running ) {

    keysPressed1 = tank1.getKeys();
    keysPressed2 = tank2.getKeys();

    if(keysPressed1[0]==true)tank1.setAngle(tank1.getAngle()-3);
    if(keysPressed1[1]==true)tank1.setAngle(tank1.getAngle()+3);
    if(keysPressed1[2]==true){
        tank1.setDX(2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(tank1.getAngle())));
        tank1.setDY(2 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(tank1.getAngle())));
    }

    if(keysPressed1[2]==false){
        tank1.setDX(0);
        tank1.setDY(0);
    }

    tank1.move();

    if(keysPressed2[0]==true)tank2.setAngle(tank2.getAngle()-3);
    if(keysPressed2[1]==true)tank2.setAngle(tank2.getAngle()+3);
    if(keysPressed2[2]==true){
        tank2.setDX( (-1) * ( 2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(tank2.getAngle()) ) ));
        tank2.setDY( (-1) * (2 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(tank2.getAngle()) ) ));
    }

    if(keysPressed2[2]==false){
        tank2.setDX(0);
        tank2.setDY(0);
    }

    tank2.move();

    repaint();
}
```

In the `Tank` class:

```
public class Tank extends Entity {

    public Tank(String type){

        this.type = type;

        if(type=="red"){
            image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("sprites/redtank1.PNG")).getImage();
            x = 200 - image.getWidth(null);
            y = 400;
        }
        if(type=="blue"){
            image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("sprites/bluetank1.PNG")).getImage();
            x = 850;
            y = 400;
        }

        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);

        angle = 0;

        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;

        keysPressed = new boolean[3];

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            keysPressed[0] = true;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            keysPressed[1] = true;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            keysPressed[2] = true;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            keysPressed[0] = true;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            keysPressed[1] = true;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            keysPressed[2] = true;
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            keysPressed[0] = false;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            keysPressed[1] = false;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            keysPressed[2] = false;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            keysPressed[0] = false;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            keysPressed[1] = false;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            keysPressed[2] = false;
        }
    }

}
```

You will probably suggest I use Key Bindings, but is there a way to still use KeyListener and have all buttons work at the same time without errors? Thanks.

Comment: `keysPressed[0]` represents left arrow AND the A key? Maybe you need a separate one for each separate key.

Comment: Each instance of the Tank object has a boolean[] keysPressed array. When A, D or W is pressed, the keysPressed of Tank2 is manipulated, and when LEFT, RIGHT or UP is pressed, the keysPressed of Tank1 is manipulated. I don't think that's the problem. Thanks for trying to help, any more ideas? :\

Comment: I think your previous statement is incorrect. If I made 1 tank object and pressed left, keysPressed[0] becomes true AND if I press A that same keysPressed[0] becomes true as well. The code to complete this is inside the tank class and is independent of which object you are working on at the time. Maybe I'm just too tired for this right now, sorry if I'm making it worse.

Comment: Just like every instance of Tank has it's own x and y variables, with their own independent values, each instance of Tank has it's own array keysPressed[].
Also, as I said in the question, both tanks can move simultaneously, and in opposite directions. They can also rotate simultaneously. The problem apears when I'm trying to rotate AND move a tank at the same time another tank is being moved AND rotated. In this case, the rotation of the second tank won't happen.

Comment: Even if there is a way, I wold still encourage you to use KeyBindings. They are intended to deal with such situations, and KeyListener is not.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a limitation of the electrical properties of your keyboard; non-"gaming" keyboards often have limited ability to detect certain combinations of three or more simultaneous keydowns. If this is the case (try the four keys in notepad, and see if the problem occurs there too) there's no software workaround possible, but mapping "forward" to a modifier key may work as a UI workaround (modifier keys are generally exempt from key ghosting).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tommorow and if your answer helped me I will marke it as accepted answer.